# How to store only 100 elements in a table

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have a room table called `scores_table`. I only want to store the last 100. How can I do this using Room?

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "score_table",
    indices = [
        Index(value = ["id"])
    ]
)
data class ScoreEntity(
    @PrimaryKey 
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    var id: Long = 0

    @ColumnInfo(name = "creation_time")
    var creationTime: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()
    ...
)
```

To insert I use this:

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun insert(entity: ScoreEntity)
```

Comment: Have a `@Transaction` function that deletes the rows that you don't want along with inserting any new ones. You would need a column in the table that allows you to determine what the "last" ones are.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44711911/android-room-database-transactions

I think this link can help

Comment: Just to add what was already said: not sure what's the purpose of the `creation_time` column, but if you have it just to know what are the freshest 100 rows, then you can use `rowid` / autoincrement primary key instead.

Then, within your `@Transaction` method you can simply obtain an id of the inserted row (`@Insert` methods can return `Long`) and delete everything that has an id lower or equal to `returnedIdValue - 100`.

Comment: @MateuszHerych that is pretty smart. If you post it I would happily accept the answer.

Comment: @J_Strauton sure - done. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's the purpose of the creation_time column, but if you have it just to know what are the freshest 100 rows, then you can use rowid / autoincrement primary key instead.

Then, within your `@Transaction` method you can simply obtain an id of the inserted row (`@Insert` methods can return `Long`, which represents an identifier of a just inserted row) and delete everything that has an id lower or equal to `returnedIdValue - 100`